# Ajax with JSON, is it a good choice for handling million elements?

Tags: ajax, json

If the resultset consists of a million of datarows (i.e. a million elements in a big array), will it make the AJAX with JSON becomes slow? In this case, Is it defeats the purpose for using AJAX & JSON because it is fast???

Comment: Don't send back a million rows.  Page that shiz.

Comment: A million elements will slow down *anything* that can serve the same purpose. The real question is, what in the world are you doing that requires a million elements at once?